# Vaadin Grid autoheight for cell

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

in my Grid a have a cell with long text .
Automatically Grid makes width:auto and I get very wide cells.
I want to make this cells more "readable" for user with

```
.dashboard .v-grid-cell{
word-wrap:all;
height:auto;
}
```

It takes no result ((
And I don't want to make all rows with same height, height or each row must be dependable of height of this cell.
You hope my question is clean ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid in Vaadin 8 and Vaadin 7 does not support rows being of variable heights. So unfortunately answer is no.

In latest versions of Vaadin Platform 10 and newer there is totally new implementation of Grid, which however supports variable row heights.